# Does pthread_once() support 'chaining' another init_routine?

Tags: linux, pthreads

Is calling another pthread_once (using a different once_control and init_routine) from within an init_routine supported?

For example,

```
static pthread_once_t gl_ctl_one = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;
static pthread_once_t gl_ctl_two = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])

{ 
   pthread_once(&gl_ctl_one, rtn_one);
};

void rtn_one() 
{ 
   printf("rtn_one\n");

   /**********************************************/
   /* Call the second init if needed             */
   /**********************************************/
   pthread_once(&gl_ctl_two, rtn_two);

   return;
} 

void rtn_two()
{ 
   printf("rtn_two\n");

   return;
}
```

I'm actually trying to init two different '.so' 'packages', so I have a need to have two separate init routines. (I can't just combine them into one, and multiple processes and threads may or may not be involved).

rtn_one() is actually in one .so, and rtn_two() is in another.

Looking at the documentaion for pthread_once at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ left me a bit confused. They mention 'recursion' as a bad idea, but only in reference to trying to use the same once_control (and I was a bit confused as to their reasoning):

"If init_routine recursively calls pthread_once() with the same once_control, the recursive call will not call the specified init_routine, and thus the specified init_routine will not complete, and thus the recursive call to pthread_once() will not return."

In my case I'm using Centos 7.5 linux, and it appears to work (I was unsure if an internal mutex in pthread_once() would cause issues or not).

But, I wasn't sure if this was promised behavior or not.